# How to include my app as account in android settings

Tags: android

I want to register/include my app account as 'Account' in android settings. What does this feature called or how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify.html). It'll answer all your questions on AccountManager that is used for this.

If you want to move ahead with AccountManager, [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html) provides more details on how to set up a custom account type.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18803194)

Comment: @SaravananSachi definitely a fair point. I answered this from my phone, but I'll take time to update my answer with the actual details shortly.